# JS not applied for dynamically generated HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic-html, redips.drag

I m using www.redips.net/ for drag/drop of objects its same as jquery but problem is that if I put everything as Static HTML then it working fine.If I generate dynamically HTML (which is must) then one of js library redips-drag-min fails to apply & drag-drop not working.

I found one solution to add reference to that js dynamically after all HTML has been created like this

```
        var ssioCss = document.createElement("script");
        ssioCss.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        ssioCss.setAttribute("src", "../redips-drag-min.js");
        document.head.appendChild(ssioCss);
```

one of the css file works this way & its great but why not the JS file can anybody help ??
Thanks

Comment: Are you giving relative path correctly? Do you see any error in the firebug? check in net tab...

Answer (score 0):

As you specify JQuery in your tags, you should use

1. [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/), or [before](http://api.jquery.com/before/) or [after](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method to create elements in your page
2. [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) to load your script
3. Use this script to load external CSS file

   ```
   $("<link/>", {
     rel: "stylesheet",
     type: "text/css",
     href: "/styles/yourcss.css"
   }).appendTo("head");
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.getScript()` for loading the external js dynamically:

```
$.getScript("../redips-drag-min.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
   console.log(data);
});
```